# jQuery UI tooltip in wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, user-interface, tooltip

Trying to get a tooltip working with a picture instead of text. As far it works with text in my site.

```
<a id="thisId" href="#" title="hello world" >ALOHA!</a>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery( '#thisId' ).tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

This works fine.. It displays "hello world" on hover of link.

But if I try the following; [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vvVwD/842/) ,but on my WP site it fails by simply not showing anything. Why could that be?

Comment: Is there error in console?

Comment: @VidyaNair no nothing.. It's a little weird.

Comment: try deactivating each plugin and check whether it is working or not

Comment: @VidyaNair but it works fine with text... So the tooltip() is working as long as its only presenting the title="" attribute.

Comment: I have checked your code with my local wp site and its working fine. make sure no error in console and scripts are loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mostly happens because your WordPress theme automatically uses Bootstrap which has its own tooltips. Its tooltips also use the same function tooltip(), so it's just a naming conflict between JQuery UI & BootStrap.

To fix this you can force renaming the tooltip() function used in JQuery Ui, like this:

```
jQuery.widget.bridge( 'jQueryUITooltip', jQuery.ui.tooltip );
```

And from now on use jQueryUITooltip() instead of tooltip() to initialize JQuery UI tooltips, example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( '#thisId' ).jQueryUITooltip({
       track: true
    });
});
```